# Going round in circles with ffmpeg concat and filter_complex

Tags: command-line, audio, ffmpeg, video

Since I've 'flipped' my classroom I'm trying to work out the ffmpeg command that will concat a set of m4a audio files with a set of matching static PNGs to create a pre-recorded talk.

I have no issues merging a single PNG (slide) and a single audio file (narration), e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 \
  -loop 1 -i 2.3-Python_the_Basics_1_1280x720.png \
  -i 2.3-1.m4a \
    -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -b:a 64k \
    out1.mp4

ffmpeg -r 30 \
  -loop 1 -i 2.3-Python_the_Basics_2_1280x720.png \
  -i 2.3-2.m4a \
    -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -b:a 64k \
    out2.mp4

ffmpeg -r 30 \
  -loop 1 -i 2.3-Python_the_Basics_3_1280x720.png \
  -i 2.3-3.m4a \
    -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -b:a 64k \
    out3.mp4
```

I can then concatenate this using the `list.txt` approach (which contains `file 'out1.mp4'` and so on):

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

However, this approach seems to insert a black frame at the start of the video, which annoys me. It might be that my life will just be easier if I just use a trim to take care of that:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.750 -i output.mp4 -t 10:00:00 -c:v copy -c:a copy cleaned.mp4
```

However, it seems to me that it *should* also be possible for me to combine *all* the audio and PNG files above into a single output in one command and that's where I go round in circles.

I'm *guessing* that one challenge here is that the `-loop 1` approach doesn't work for multiple PNG inputs because I should be specifying a time for each when dealing with a complex filter. But I don't want to hard-code the duration because the automation angle is all about being able to re-record just a part of my talk (so changing the audio track for a single slide) and then re-render the video in its entirety. Meaning that the length of the audio track might change so I don't want to have to update the PNG looping time manually.

I've found the `concat` filter rather difficult to puzzle out, but the following is the *kind* of thing I was hoping would work (except it obviously doesn't):

```
ffmpeg -r 30 \
  -loop 1 -i 2.3-Python_the_Basics_1_1280x720.png \
  -loop 1 -i 2.3-Python_the_Basics_2_1280x720.png \
  -loop 1 -i 2.3-Python_the_Basics_3_1280x720.png \
  -i 2.3-1.m4a \
  -i 2.3-2.m4a \
  -i 2.3-3.m4a \
  -filter_complex "[0:v][3:a] [1:v][4:a] [2:v][5:a] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [vvv][aaa]" \
  -map "[vvv]" -map "[aaa]" \
  -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p \
  -c:a aac -b:a 64k \
  out6.mp4
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want without using the `list.txt` approach? Some sort of per-segment `shortest` option on `[0:v][3:a]`, `[1:v][4:a]`, etc.?

Using `ffprobe` to capture the clip lengths into script parameters would work but seems... inelegant. I.e. capturing this for every audio track and then writing it out as part of the `ffmpeg` 'script' in the `-t` parameter for the PNG files:

```
ffprobe -sexagesimal -show_entries format=duration 2.3-1.m4a
```

Many thanks!